# Tried to download images with Python lib, but nothing happens and don't get any errors

Tags: python, image, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I try to download images from Google Image Search service, with no luck. I got only information:
"Unfortunately all 20 could not be downloaded because some images were not downloadable. 0 is all we got for this search filter!" message multiple times I run the app.

Errors: zero

I downloaded chromedriver and selenium is present in my VENV. I run this app from Windows / PyCharm Pro.

```
import time
from google_images_download import google_images_download

search_queries = [
    'Nissan GT-R 2020',
    'Ford Puma 2020',
    'Porsche Macan',
    'VW Touareg 2020'
]

response = google_images_download.googleimagesdownload()

for query in search_queries:
        arguments = {
            "keywords": query,
            "limit": 50,
            "print_urls": True,
            #"size": "medium",
            "output_directory": "E:\\IMAGES",
            "image_directory": f"IMAGES\\{query}",
            "chromedriver": "E:\\IMAGES\\Chrome\\chromedriver.exe"
            }
        paths = response.download(arguments)
        print(paths)
        time.sleep(15)
```

I don't see in docs how to use selenium, there is only information, how to add chromedriver path.

I use ChromeDriver 80.0.3987.16 - a little older than my Chrome Browser, which version number ends with 150.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you can use `driver.get(url)` normally.

Check whether the page use `<iframe>` tag.(if it use,then you must use switch_to.iframe() ).

Or not,You can try to use `WebDriverWait()`.

Comment: I will try your recommendations. But here I don't use chromedriver and selenium directly but via google_images_download library.